# добавить запись по условию в временную таблицу в ms sql

Tags: sql-server

есть таблица

`Date        FIO          ESP          LFL%

2019-04-30  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот     50
2019-05-31  CИДОРОВ    Чеки             70
2019-05-31  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот     80
2019-05-31  CИДОРОВ    Прибыль          23
2019-05-31  CИДОРОВ    Отток            65
2019-06-30  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот     21
2019-06-30  CИДОРОВ    Прибыль          45
2019-07-31  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот     64
2019-07-31  CИДОРОВ    Прибыль          23
2019-07-31  CИДОРОВ    Отток            15`

в которой есть четыре показателя,Товарооборот,Чеки,Отток,Прибыль!
Если например за 2019-04-30 у нас только Товарооборот то нужно отобразить еще три показателя на эту дату, если в одну дату входят 4 показателя
, то так и оставляем, как за 2019-05-31, в итоге должно получится

`Date      FIO          ESP          LFL%

2019-04-30  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот     50
2019-04-30  CИДОРОВ     Чеки           null
2019-04-30  CИДОРОВ    Прибыль         null
2019-04-30  CИДОРОВ     Отток          null
2019-05-31  CИДОРОВ    Чеки             70
2019-05-31  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот     80
2019-05-31  CИДОРОВ    Прибыль          23
2019-05-31  CИДОРОВ    Отток            65
2019-06-30  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот     21
2019-06-30  CИДОРОВ    Прибыль          45
2019-06-30  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот    null
2019-06-30  CИДОРОВ    Прибыль         null
2019-07-31  CИДОРОВ    Товарооборот     64
2019-07-31  CИДОРОВ    Прибыль          23
2019-07-31  CИДОРОВ    Отток            15
2019-07-31  CИДОРОВ    Чеки            null`

Comment: сделайте таблицу/подзапрос с этими четырьмя строками и прилефтджойньте к таблице своей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сначала отобрать уникальные сочетания даты и ФИО, потом соединить результат со всеми имеющимися вариантами показателей. Ну а потом соединять уже с самой таблицей данных, выбирая оттуда проценты или что у вас там хранится в столбце LFL%.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([Date] date, [FIO] nvarchar(50), [ESP] nvarchar(15), [LFL%] tinyint)

INSERT @T
VALUES ('2019-04-30', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Товарооборот', 50)
      ,('2019-05-31', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Чеки',         70)
      ,('2019-05-31', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Товарооборот', 80)
      ,('2019-05-31', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Прибыль',      23)
      ,('2019-05-31', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Отток',        65)
      ,('2019-06-30', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Товарооборот', 21)
      ,('2019-06-30', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Прибыль',      45)
      ,('2019-07-31', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Товарооборот', 64)
      ,('2019-07-31', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Прибыль',      23)
      ,('2019-07-31', N'CИДОРОВ', N'Отток',        15)

;WITH [DatesCTE]
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           [Date]
          ,[FIO]
      FROM @T
),
[ESPCTE]
AS
(
    SELECT [DatesCTE].[Date]
          ,[DatesCTE].[FIO]
          ,[ESPs].[ESP]
      FROM [DatesCTE]
           CROSS APPLY (
                           SELECT N'Чеки' AS [ESP]
                            UNION ALL
                           SELECT N'Товарооборот'
                            UNION ALL
                           SELECT N'Прибыль'
                            UNION ALL
                           SELECT N'Отток'
                       ) AS [ESPs]
)
SELECT [ESPCTE].[Date]
      ,[ESPCTE].[FIO]
      ,[ESPCTE].[ESP]
      ,[T].[LFL%]
  FROM [ESPCTE]
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @T [T]
       ON [T].[Date] = [ESPCTE].[Date] AND
          [T].[FIO] = [ESPCTE].[FIO] AND
          [T].[ESP] = [ESPCTE].[ESP]
```

Answer (score 1):

Нечто подобное можно использовать.

```
WITH esp as (
    SELECT 'товарооборот' as t
    UNION
    SELECT 'Прибыль' 
    .....
)
SELECT d.*
FROM data AS d 
RIGHT JOIN esp ON (esp.t = data.esp)
```